# Intermittent Response "Unauthenticated requests are not allowed" in node express

Tags: html, node.js, api, express

**Here is the code**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("server is running at port 3000");
});
app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
app.post("/",function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body.fiat);
    res.send("Your currency is " + req.body.fiat);
    // res.send("Your price is "+ price);

});
request("https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/BTCUSD",function(error, response, body){
    var data  = JSON.parse(body);
    var price = data.last;
    console.log(price);
});
```

When I run the above code, sometime I get the `Unauthenticated requests are not allowed` error and sometime I get the required output like this,

```
server is running at port 3000
11539.26
```

**Why is it happening, what might be the reason behind this?**

Comment: The issue seems to be with your API: `https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/BTCUSD`, do you have a registered plan / API key with them?

Comment: Accessing some routes or apis require some key, so you have to get your allowing access api key then provide it the headers of the requests

Comment: no I do not have registered plan or api key. I am following a tuturial and I dont think in that tutorial, the tutor has used any key or have a registered plan. But the thing is, why  do I get the response sometime?

Comment: @AmanChaudhary see the link -https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/BTCUSD

Comment: I am also using the same link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: As per the BitcoinAverage documentaion:Every request must contan x-ba-key header]
You should go through bitcoin average documentation, As you have mentioned you are following any tutorial, maybe, that tutor will not be revealing his key for some reasons.

Comment: I have created a free account with 14 days free trial.
I have a public key now. Can you help me how can I use that api key to get the data